# ASP.NET-MVC4 Code Not Running

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, justmock

I have a simple MVC4 solution that works just fine until I set a breakpoint in the controller.  If I do that, the breakpoint does not hit, and I get a pop-up window titled, "Source Not Available" that goes on to say "Code not running", then "The current thread is not currently running code or the call stack could not be obtained."

The application will run as long as I do not want to debug.  Any clues?

Answer (score 7):

Full disclosure: I work at Telerik.

Thanks for the report and I'm sorry for the caused inconvenience. Actually there is an easier workaround. You can just disable the JustMock profiler from its Visual Studio extension menu: http://screencast.com/t/mPALFVJnuXm. Then you don't need to uninstall it. And when you run your unit tests which include mocked tests, just enable JustMock from the same menu again.

This is a known issue which we've already fixed. The fix will be publicly available in our Service Pack which is scheduled to be released next week. Please update your JM installation once the SP is live.

Comment: Hello Everyone, just to let you know that we've released a new version (v.2013.3.1101.2) of JustMock which fixes the above mentioned issue. Please update to it. It's an internal build but we'll make our best to make it Service Pack next week.

Comment: I have the latest internal build of JustMock (as of today 4 Nov 3012) and have the same problem occur in VS 2013. Disabling JustMock did solve it, but thought you should know the latest build does not appear to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, @TrueBlueAussie. Can you please file a support ticket with details for the issue? But if you prefer, you can share here what your project type is, and any other details you think are important. Unfortunately we can't reproduce with ASP.NET MVC 4 project under VS 2013 :/

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Telerik JustMock as a mocking framework and have recently updated it to the 2013 Q3 version, it causes this exact problem. I was able to resolve this issue by uninstalling the mocking framework and installing the 2013 Q2 version.